# Cannot find 'BGTaskScheduler' in scope

Tags: ios, swift, bgtaskscheduler

Anyone knows how to fix this error in ios swift ***Cannot find 'BGTaskScheduler' in scope*** i am trying to run background task where i am using BGTaskScheduler

Answer (score 30):

You need to import this

```
import BackgroundTasks
```

Comment: Why doesn't Xcode has an auto import? Frustrating apple IDE...

Comment: Why don't Apple docs have this, is the biggest frustration.